# asp.net web api how to create zip file from multiple server files and download the zip file in your machine

Tags: c#, angularjs, download, httpresponse, zip

I am trying to get multiple files from network and zip into one file and then open a window to allow user to save the zipped file in his/her machine.

My current working code zips the files and return it to client in angularJS, but it doesn't initiate the download. From client I am making the git call which gets the object list and pass it to downloadFiles function. I want to handle the download from API, not from client side.
//obj List contains all the files information that needs to be downloaded in zip

```
public HttpResponseMessage downloadFiles(List<obj> arr)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (var d in arr)
            {
                zip.AddEntry(d.FileName, d.URL);
            }
            return ZipContentResult(zip);
        }
    }

    protected HttpResponseMessage ZipContentResult(ZipFile zipFile)
    {
        var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
        {
            zipFile.Save(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }, "application/zip");

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = pushStreamContent };
    }
```